# Ember js how to set controller's model with DS.FixtureAdapter?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How to set controller's model properly?

Here is my code (getting error):

```
<script>
   window.App = Ember.Application.create();

   App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 11,
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
   });

   App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function() {
     this.controllerFor('topic').set('model', App.Topic.find());
    }
   });

   App.Topic =  DS.Model.extend({
    label: DS.attr('string'),
    selected: DS.attr('boolean')
   });

   App.Topic.FIXTURES = [
     { id: 1, label: '1. First topic', selected: true },
     { id: 2, label: '2. Second topic' },
     { id: 3, label: '3. Third topic' },
   ];

   App.TopicController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();

   App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    content: [],
    test: 'INDEX TEST',
    currentTopics: null
   });
</script>
```

Template ( trying to bind TopicController to Ember.Select view )

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">

  {{view Ember.Select
     contentBinding="App.TopicController"
     selectionBinding="currentTopics"
     optionLabelPath="content.label"
     optionValuePath="content.id"}}

</script>
```

**Versions:**
ember 1.0.0-pre4
ember-data revision 11

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aFPy7/3/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a discussion going on about this [**here**](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2007), but as of now, Ember Controllers use the alias `content` for `model`, so your `setupController` should be:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function() {
    this.controllerFor('topic').set('content', App.Topic.find());
  }
});
```

Additionally, you can check out **[this sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/dWcUp/)** that uses the `FixtureAdapter`. Just keep in mind this is a work in progress and I'll be updating it as I find time.

http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/KjWKw/

Comment: Thanks. I've changed to 'content' and looks like it is ok, but I still  can't figure out how to add contentBinding to view Ember.Select. I've tried this
    `{{view Ember.Select`
       `contentBinding="App.TopicController.content"` but getting _Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'length' on an undefined object._

Comment: try setting simply `content` (or `view.content`). I think the way you're setting the binding has been deprecated sometime ago

Comment: i spent the whole freaking day trying to get ember-data to work and this version of it finally got my app working, thank you!